# при фокусироке на input съезжает весь header в safari ios

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

Всем привет.

Появилась такая проблема, при фокусировке на input и появлении клавиатуры, сверху появляется пустое пространство.

header имеет position fixed, а input absolute относительно родительского контейнера.

Проблема появляется исключительно на ios в браузере safari

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]